# Как протетистировать на сервере верификацию покупки в Google Pay?

Tags: php, python, python-3.x, google-play, google-pay

Сценарий: в андроид приложении совершается покупка в google pay. На сервер передается ProductId(SKU) и PurchaseToken(Код для верификации покупки). Сервер должен сделать запрос к google pay, проверить что покупка была или нет.

Сам код простой, примеры для php и python : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33850864/how-to-verify-purchase-for-android-app-in-server-side-google-play-in-app-billin

**Вопрос в чем**: как потестировать верификацию покупки без приложения, ну и собственно говоря без покупки? Цель: написать разные сценарии под разные ответы и посмотреть работоспособность серверной части, без участия приложения.  **Уточнение:** вопрос не про автоматические тестирование, а про то, **как мне сделать хоть один успешный запрос к гуглу?**

Есть раздел в гугле про тестирование: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html

Но как я понял это про тестирование покупок из приложения, да и нет никакой информации про тестовый purchaseToken.

Comment: Вам обязательно в тесте использовать интеграцию с google-play? Кажется, что это довольно сложно и дорого в плане реализации. Рассматриваете ли Вы иные варианты?

Comment: @hedgehogues а какие есть еще варианты?

Comment: mock-сервис (ещё 5 символов)

Comment: @hedgehogues ну ок, если я замокаю для автоматического тстирования. Но как мне вообще проверить работу  своих скриптов? Правильно ли обращаюсь к гуглу, все ил я учел, да и чтобы мок составить, мне нужно знать какие ответы возможны у реального сервиса. Разве нет?

Answer (score 1):

Здесь вопрос выбора. Вы всегда можете сделать какую-нибудь интеграцию. Но не всегда эта интеграция будет полезна. Как Вы собираетесь проверять: прошёл тест или нет? Это может быть сложным. В случае мока, предлагается проверять корректность работы контракта Вашего сервиса. Тестировать саму интеграцию предлагается руками (т.е. Вы руками проверяете, что всё работает). Затем, уповаете на случай. Конечно, можно призвать на помощь selenium. Но, как я уже говорил, это может быть проблемно в плане поддержки и дорого в плане разработки.

В случае, если Вы задумаете использовать selenium (или аналог) будте готовы, что вёрстка может меняться, компоненты могут ехать и т.д. Для мобильных приложений наверняка есть аналоги selenium.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, апну рейтинг. Но вопрос не о том немного. Мне (серверу) должны приходить данные от приложения - id покупки и Хэш покупки (алгоритм не известен). Как мне без приложеения на руках написать сервис который работает с гугл плей и посмотреть, работает ли он (мой сервис)? Правильно ли он обрабатывает ответы, правильно ля я заложил логику на запись заказов и т.д.? Даже чтобы мок написать - мне нужно знать что возращает реальный сервис, чтобы его замокать. А как я узнаю, если не могу к нему обратиться без приложения? Вопрос в этом. А не как написать автоматические тесты

Comment: У вас есть сервис? А что он делает? Чем он занимается?

Comment: у меня сервис, который вызывает готовую бибилотеку google play. В зависимости от ответа гугла - логика сервера та или иная. Но я не знаю ответ гугл плей, потому что мне возращается только http 400.  Да я могу замокать библиотеку от гугла, но мне надо знать что она возращает в тех или иных случаях. А я не могу это сделать, так как приложение не готово, а тестовых данных (sku и token) я не могу найти, если они вообще есть.

Comment: У Вас есть use-cases?

Comment: Что вы под эти подразмумеваете, диаграмму или просто логику описать?

Comment: Логику. Я не прошу Вас здесь это писать. Напишите тесты на use-cases. Проделайте эти действия сначала руками, чтобы убедиться, что google отвечает так, как нужно. Если всё работает руками перенесите эти действия в код, в тесты, так как если бы Вы работали с реальным приложением. И оставьте тесты не рабочими до тех пор, пока не появится приложение. Когда оно появится, тесты потихоньку начнут проходить

Comment: Вот вы пишете "Проделайте эти действия сначала руками, чтобы убедиться, что google отвечает так, как нужно". В этом и есть вопрос. Как мне добиться ответа от гугла, когда у меня нет ни productId ни PurchaseToken?  Я не могу обратиться к нему без участия реального android app, по крайней мере не знаю как. И вариантов ответа я от него не знаю. Вопрос не про тестирование через phpunit вопрос о взаимодейсвтие с google api.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106787/discussion-between-hedgehogues-and-pavel).